# Use a Variable in a structured Table Reference?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have several tables of financial forecasts (Revenue, Cost, Staff, etc). Each forecast has a unique name (FY14-1, FY14-2, etc.) I would like to use a variable in a structured table reference to get the variable the user has selected in a pick list.

For Example if the Users picks forecast cycle "FY13-1" then I want the revenue formula to be something like this:

```
=RevenueProjections[[#Totals],[" & **C2** &"]]
```

where C2 is the cell that holds the drop down list selection
I've also tried:

```
=INDEX(RevenueProjections[#All],ROW(RevenueProjections[#Totals]),MATCH(Control!C2,RevenueProjections[#Headers],0))
```

Any hint would be most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Mixing structured references and relative referencing in a table is not a good idea. The behaviour is inconsistent and has been filed as a bug with the Excel team, but the response was that this is by design.

So, in this case, use conventional referencing instead of structured references.  If you need help with that, please update your question and post a sample of your data structure, desired results and the business logic.